# Telethon gets disauthenticated on armv6 (but not armv7)

Tags: python, telethon

My question is: I would like to know if there is a way to enable a debug on telethon library as initially I thought it was Telegram related but now it seems more like arch (os/python..?) related:

Facts:
-armv6 (raspberyy pi1, busterOS, python3): telethon client authenticates (with .start()) and disconnects after 3-5 minutes(!). Need to resend request/receive auth sms and it stays connected for another 3-5 minutes after which asks again for phone number

-armv7(raspberry pi4, busterOS, python3): telethon client authenticates (with .start()) and STAYS authenticated, as it should

Python version(Python 3.7.3), telethon package (Telethon1.23.0) are STRICTLY the same, only the architecture is a generation different between the two devices.
(What worth noticing (probably) is that when using armv6 (and having another session opened also on a phone), when the disauthenthication happens on armv6 the phone app gets logged out of telegram also, like a "disconnect ALL sessions" request is taking place all of a sudden)

Comment: Yes, you can enable DEBUG logging. The documentation explains how https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html.

Comment: Thank Lonami. I've enabled debugging meanwhile, unfortunately only to confirm the logging out is happening outside telethon, even when nothing is happening on OS or phone side; phone session,(and any other already authenticated with the same credentials) gets logged out automatically at the telegram servers level. Most probably there is an internal scheduled task that checks against something related to the last device id/specs (something that does not like about it) and it decides to discard the auth token for that session (and it triggers a logout of all sessions)

Answer (score 0):

I found why I had the disauthentication. The difference between the two devices was not the arch generation but the kernel NAME, not the version.
The device that triggered the disauthentication had a kernel name like *4.16.30CUSTOM* while the "good" device had it like *4.16.30-v7lCUSTOM*.

I recompiled the "broken" device's kernel using a custom name like *4.16.30-vxCUSTOM* (using a dash `-`) and now everything is working.

Later edit: the `default_system_version` is split from the Kernel name (aka `system.release`) in telegrambaseclient.py file:
`default_system_version = re.sub(r'-.+','',system.release)`